Overpass query for admin_level parents for an area
Using Overpass I'm trying to get the admin_level 2, 4, and 6 parents of wikidata Q16557 (Dallas, Texas, but I want to be able to do this for any US city).
This query works fine for admin_level = 6 (returning all five counties that the city of Dallas is in):
[out:json];
area[wikidata=Q16557]->.a;
(
   relation[boundary=administrative][wikidata][wikipedia][admin_level~"6"](area.a);
);
out tags;

But if I change it to admin_level 4, I'm expecting to get Texas, but I get no results:
[out:json];
area[wikidata=Q16557]->.a;
(
   relation[boundary=administrative][wikidata][wikipedia][admin_level~"4"](area.a);
);
out tags;

And if I change it to admin_level 2, I'm expecting to get the United States, but I still get no results:
[out:json];
area[wikidata=Q16557]->.a;
(
   relation[boundary=administrative][wikidata][wikipedia][admin_level~"2"](area.a);
);
out tags;

Is my original query correct?  It always seems to work with finding the county(ies) a city is in.
Is there any reason it would work for admin_level 6 but not 4 or 2?

You have to use recursive up relations statement like:
[out:json];
area[wikidata=Q16557]->.a;
relation[boundary=administrative][wikidata]
[wikipedia][admin_level~"6"](area.a) -> .rel;
    
// below line just copy .rel to .a
.rel -> .a; 

// this one finds all upper level relations where 
// .a are part(s) of them and removes (-) .rel
(.a <<; - rel.a;) -> .b;

(rel.b[admin_level="4"];);
    
out geom tags;

https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1Ugs

Edited:
If you wish go back one level, to children relations, use >> (recursive down) statement like:
[...]
rel.b[admin_level="4"] -> .c;

.c >> -> .d;

(rel.d["boundary"="administrative"][wikidata];);
out geom tags;


https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1Uld

Thanks, Grzegorz -- I'll have to study. I was hoping for something that didn't require recursion to get both the parents and children admin levels of any wikidata id.  This works for the children, but not the parents:
[out:json];area[wikidata=<wikidata>]->.a; relation[admin_level~"<admin_level(s)>"](area.a); out tags; and it's relatively quick to retrieve them.  I.e., all counties in Georgia: [out:json];area[wikidata=Q1428]->.a; relation[admin_level~"6"](area.a); out tags;

Don't know your specific case but I would rather download the USA .pbf, extract the boundaries/places (towns/cities/etc) and play with it spatially (st_within(), st_covered_by() kinds of function) than mess with overpass. :)

I'm not familiar with that but I'll look at it.

I wanted to get away from recursion since I suspect it's slower and I also wonder if it's necessary, but this is the solution I ended up with:
[out:json];
area[wikidata=<wikidata id>]->.a;
(relation[wikidata][wikipedia](area.a); <<;)->.p;
relation.p[admin_level~"<admin_level(s)>"];
out tags;

Many thanks @Grzegorz Sapijaszko for pointing me in this direction and providing the correct answer to my initial question, which was poorly worded for my actual requirements.
I didn't end up using his solution in my application because the solution here is more succinct and it returns all the admin_levels, which is what I wanted although that admittedly strays from the question I had originally asked.
